# Inserting XMLHTTP responseText to HTMLDocument generates Automation Error

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use `XMLHTTP` object in VBA to retrive HTML document and insert it to a `HTMLDocument` object for manipulating elements. But my codes got automation errors. I thoughly checked the codes but couldn't find any possible causes. Can someone help me fix the problem?

Many thanks in avance!

VBA Codes:

```
Sub RetrieveData()

Dim strURL As String
Dim strResponse As String
Dim objResponse As Object
Dim objHttpReq As Object
Dim objHTML As New HTMLDocument

strURL = "http://www.customs.go.jp/toukei/srch/indexe.htm?M=57&   P=1,1,,,,,,,,,,2013,,9,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"

Set objHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
objHttpReq.Open "GET", strURL, False
objHttpReq.send

strResponse = objHttpReq.responseText

objHTML.body.innerHTML = strResponse

MsgBox objHTML.body.innerHTML

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than attempting to set the body (which should really work) as you have a full html document you can;

```
Dim objHTMLAs Object
Set objHTML= CreateObject("htmlfile") 

objHTML.open
objHTML.write objHttpReq.responseText
objHTML.Close
```

Comment: Really appreciate your reply. I am now able to fetch the document in HTML but there's another issue about the Iframe. Actually I need to get the details about the Frame document and I used contentDocument property of Iframe object. But the result turn out to be "Unspecified Error." for contentDocument. I would like to ask how I can extract the Iframe document in that link?